# Using Apple automator to delete portion of filename before file extension

Tags: macos, filenames, rename, automator

I have files named filename_hdpi.png

With automator, I'm targeting these images, but when trying to strip off the _hdpi part of the filename with Rename finder items it doesn't work.

My workflow is attached. The file doesn't renames or moves with this workflow, it remains unchanged.

[image: workflow]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you make sure you don't have a file with the same name as the one being renamed?

Comment: Right! That was the problem. Thanks!